# bootstrap well component - specify width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use bootstrap's well component on a horizontal form.

Most rows of the form only have one or two fields in a set of columns, and I am specifying the width of each column.

I would like to style some of the of rows in a well, but I don't want to have the well go across the entire screen, because it looks weird to have so much extra space to the right of the fields. I only want to style the maximum width of the columns in the rows.

If enclose the grid within a div of a set size, then all of the controls' sizes and positioning are affected.

Is there anyway to style a row this way?

Is there a way to create a div that has the right width, and position underneath the actual rows?

Comment: You can put `.well` in a column or otherwise in an element with a contained width. Doesn't have to be full-width. Share what you have so far if you want help.

Comment: That doesn't work, because if I put .well in each column it's not smooth gradient across the columns.

I really want to be able to specify the maximum width of the well without having to specify the width of the well's container, because doing so affects every other control's width, since the col-... classes base themselves on the containers size that they are in.